# how to handle the Navigation in Seprate file in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am new to React native 
I want to manage navigation in a component separate from App.js Component.

I could not understand how to handle in a separate component file

```js
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer style={{ backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF' }}>
      <Stack.Navigator>

        <Stack.Screen name=" " component={FirstPage}   
          options={{
            headerLeft: () => (
              <Button
                onPress={() => alert('This is a button!')}
                title="Info"
                color="#fff"
              />
            ),
          }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginView}
          options={{
            headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: '#88aa31',
            },

            headerTintColor: '#fff',
            headerLeft: () => (
              <Button
                onPress={() => alert('This is a button!')}
                title="Info"
                color="#fff"
              />
            ),
          }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen name="Signup" component={SignUpView}
          options={{
            headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: '#88aa31',
            },
            headerTintColor: '#fff',
          }}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This my App.js file. How can i manage navigation in a separated component in React Native?

Answer (score 0):

Create navigation file import all other components you want as show below in code.

```
import { createAppContainer, createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import LoginView from './App/component/Views/Login'
import SignUpView from './App/component/Views/Signup';

const SwitchNavigator = createStackNavigator(
    {
        LoginView: { screen: LoginView },
        SignUpView: { screen: SignUpView }
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'LoginView',
    }
);

const App = createAppContainer(SwitchNavigator)

export default App;
```